# Invalid Selector Exception while running Appium tests on Sauce Labs

Tags: android, xpath, appium, ui-automation, saucelabs

The xpath I am using is for an Android app :

`//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'etPass')]`

This xpath works fine when I run the test locally on real device or VM.

But when I run the same test on Sauce Labs, it gives me Invalid Selector Exception.

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 
An error occurred while searching for an element by XPath. (WARNING: 
The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 88 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: 
http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
```

When I use xpath with `@text` instead of `@resource-id`, it works. Why is it that Sauce Labs does not recognise `@resource-id` as a valid attribute to find xpath?

Below is the screenshot of uiautomatorviewer with xml

[image: UiAutomatorViewer screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried `//android.widget.EditText[contains(@id,'etPass')]` this ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. It does not consider the condition.

So `//android.widget.EditText[contains(@id,'etPass')]` is same as `//android.widget.EditText` . It just goes to the first EditText element on the screen which happens to be Username box, not password box

Comment: @BludShot : please update the question with your code block and appium inspector screenshot for the elements mentioned to get things clear

Comment: @BludShot agree with nullpointer. please post your uiautomator hierarchy / XML

Comment: I've updated the question with screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing it shall be using  this :

```
//android.widget.EditText[contains(@id,'etPass')] //resource-id is not a recognised attribute for selection
```

Also, if you need to be specific to selecting a single element using x-path :

```
//android.widget.EditText[@id='etPass'] // = ensures the value match for specified attribute
```

Comment: But it's not working. 

`//android.widget.EditText[contains(@id,'etPass')]` returns me the username box instead of password box because username box is the first EditText element on the screen.

Comment: `//android.widget.EditText[@id='etPass'] ` is also not working.

It is not considering id as an attribute. The same happens when I use any garbage value instead of id, that is, it returns me the first EditText element